# Tutorial on these tags "highLT"><"highELE">html"highGT">>

Tags: javascript

I am new to script-languages and I am studying on the webstie W3schools.com
But what I cannot find is an explanation on these tags:

"highLT" highELE" "highGT

Is this a coding language for html5 or javascript or ... ?
Can you guys send me a link to a site with the explanations ?

Thanks a lot 
Désir

Comment: No such things exist.

Comment: `I am studying on the webstie W3schools.com` - there's your first mistake. `"highLT" highELE" "highGT` - where did you see that? ... looks like some weird notation for `<html>` ... i.e. `&lt;html&gt;`